# Saving images to a given location

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to take screenshots of the iPhone app view and save the images to a given location.

My code below saves the images to the photo library, but I want to save it to some other given location. Is it possible to do so? Please help me up.

My code is here:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, self, nil, nil);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use NSData to store the image data.

To save the image:

```
 NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage)];  
[imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
```

To retrieve the image:

```
 UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

Update #1: Example (I can't test the example right now but it should work this way):

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);  
self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];  
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();   
// Get the location of the Documents directory  
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) ;  
NSString *imagePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  
NSString *filename = @"test.png" ;   
NSString *filepath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", imagePath, filename];  
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();  
// Save the image   
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage)];  
[imageData writeToFile:filepath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: can you pls provide me an example to try with my code...i mean when i tried your code with my uiimage its not working...pls shown me how to do it

Comment: I've added an example with your code. However, I can't test the code right now. But I'm pretty sure it should work that way.

Comment: can you pls tell me ...where the image is being saved when running your code...i am new to iphone devlopment

Comment: It's saved in the documents directory

Comment: thank you..it saves the image noww...but the size of the image is much bigger than the actual size...pls help me out