# Help required to attain the actual image size

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

[Saving images to a given location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130764/save-images-to-the-given-location/4130792#4130792)

i followed the above link and it works but i dont get actual image size...it is much bigger...
how can i fix it...

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you mean - bigger?

The screen is 320x480 pixels. So if you the view you're saving is the whole screen, that's what you'll get.

Depending on your (computer) screen resolution, this may look quite big or quite small, and will almost certainly look different than the actual size of the iphone screen.