# How can we print an ipad view containg uiimage and a uitableview of multiple rows

Tags: ipad, ios, printing, sdk

i have a view containing uiscrollview ..which contain uiimage of size 1000*1000 and also a uitable view having multipele row..uitable view itself scrolling adn we can also scroll the entire image..tableview is subview of uiimage present there..how can i print the entire things??

Answer (score 1):

To print it you basically have to draw everything out to a temporary PDF, graphics and text, and then send it out for printing.

The **[Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)** explains how to do everything.

**Edit**

There is an alternate, but the quality will be very low: you can capture the screen (renderInContext, as described by [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130435/help-on-capturing-screen)) and then print the image.

Text will be jaggy and fuzzy, though better with with a Retina Display device.

Comment: i read ur answer , its useful only when there is no content hidden, means we need to scroll down or up to see that contents, what we do in the alternate case , that is entire things not displayed ,part of the table cell are visible, remaining are show only when scrolling,,how can i convert the entire thing(including the hidden things also)

Comment: Read the first part, that's the real answer. You can't just print it, you have to create a new document that contains everything you want to print using UIKit, Quartz, and/or OpenGL. The link I provided explains everything, but there's a lot to learn. The section on Generating PDF Content is the core of the creation process: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH10-SW1